# pass current user.id in text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I pass the value of the current user_id using text_field_tag?

Using form_for I did `<%= f.text_field :subject, :value => "You have a message from #{@user.id}" %>`

When I insert the same user.id into `<%= text_field_tag :subject, "You have a message from"%>` it does not work. Is this possible with form_for?

Comment: `<%= text_field_tag :subject, "You have a message from"%>` - this is the exact code you are using to set user.id value into text field? If it's different, can you please provide the exact you are using it. Cause in this one I don't see a `user.id` in value.

Comment: @rmagnum2002 I took the user.id value out because it was not working. It would either show user.id as text (not the value) or be hidden.

Comment: see if you can join this chat:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48785/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-22120491-pass-current-user-id-in-text-field-ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
  <%= text_field_tag :subject, "You have a message from #{@user.id} " %>
```

if it doesn't , try this

```
  <%= text_field_tag :subject, nil , value: "You have a message from #{@user.id} " %>
```

If still no luck , do this

```
  <% text = "You have a message from #{@user.id}" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :subject, text %>
```

Comment: try this, do this, I was looking to api and there is no way you can set `value:` to text_field_tag as you specified in line 2. Also line 3 is no good too, cause it's the same thing as line one where you just use a variable as value. None will work if user variable is not loaded.

Comment: I passed `current_user` instead of `user.id` and it works as expected. Thanks for the assistance guys!

Comment: @rmagnum2002 , haha.. i know, you read what is written in documentation but didn't bother to check the sourcecode (lucky which i always do). See this, https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4179470f0116a08a1838c474ba5541bb33658c9d/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L171

Comment: :) useless without the user variable.  +1 for the source code ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= text_field_tag :subject, "You have a message from user #{User.first.id} " %>
```

this will return

> "You have a message from user 1"

where `1` is the `id` of the first `user` in db, assuming you have at least one `user` in db. This way you'll be sure there is nothing wrong with `text_field_tag`. If the above works for you, you need to double check if `@user` variable is loaded in controller action so you can use it in form:

```
<%= text_field_tag :subject, "You have a message from user #{@user.id}" %>
```